# How to set up VS Code debugger for Angular app, which is inside+run-by .Net Core Api project?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

**Projects' structure:**

```
APIProject
 ↓AngularApp
   ↓.vscode
      launch.json
      tasks.json
   package.json
 Startup.cs
```

When running APIProject using `dotnet watch run`, I want to automatically run AngularApp with its debugger.

Currently, AngularApp with its debugger can be run directly using `ng serve`. (Tutorial followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XGR-Fb3XZE )

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // (un-related code skipped)

    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "AngularApp/dist";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // (un-related code skipped)

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "AngularApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

**package.json** (un-related parts skipped)

```
{
  "name": "AngularApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-debug": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run AngularApp:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build"
  }
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "debug-angular-serve",
      "type": "msedge",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start-debug",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "start-debug",
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "dedicated"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "typescript",
                "source": "ts",
                "applyTo": "closedDocuments",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${cwd}"
                ],
                "pattern": "$tsc",
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": true,
                    "beginsPattern": {
                        "regexp": "(.*?)"
                    },
                    "endsPattern": {
                        "regexp": "Compiled |Failed to compile."
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Inside Configure() of Startup.cs, I tried to use npm script of launch.json. But failed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked: I added a launch.json in Asp.Net project's .vscode folder. Nothing else is needed in .vscode folders of both Asp.Net and Angular projects.

**launch.json of .vscode of Asp.net project:**

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
        "type": "pwa-msedge",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "https://localhost:44380/eos/app-config/system-users",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/ClientApp",
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*"
        }
    }
]
```

}

First, ran the Asp.net project by `dotnet watch run`. Then, in debug view of VS Code, clicked the green button after selecting 'Launch Edge against localhost'.